# How to properly cut first N bytes from beginning of a file in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, file

```
NSString *pathOfFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", file];
NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:pathOfFile];
[fh seekToFileOffset:30];
NSData *data = [fh readDataToEndOfFile];
[fh writeData:nil];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:file contents:data attributes:nil];
```

I want to cut the first 30 bytes of a file.
What I get is:

```
mbp:Debug me$ hexdump -C File1
00000000  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000000b0  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000000f0  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000120
mbp:Debug me$ hexdump -C File1
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000000d0  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000100
```

Why it zeros out insted of being cut?

Comment: On first glance, `NSString *pathOfFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", file];` does not make sense.  If file is not an NSString object, then `NSString *pathOfFile = [file description];` would be better. If it is an NSString, then `NSString *pathOfFile = file;` or `NSString *pathOfFile = [file copy];` if you must.

Comment: ye. I removed applicationPath and forgot to change it. But it still works.

Comment: What makes you say it isn't cut?  The movement of the few non-zero bytes of the file and reduction in overall length seems to suggest that you successfully removed the start of the file.  What is a little confusing is why the overall length (but not the offset of non-zero bytes) seems to have shrunk by 32 bytes instead of 30, but that might be hexdump being weird (the program is notorious for doing other than what one might expect, though it what it does probably is consistent with its documentation)

Answer (score 0):

all in all I came up with this:

```
    NSString *pathOfFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", file];
NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:pathOfFile];
[fh seekToFileOffset:30];
NSData *data = [fh readDataToEndOfFile];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(30, [data length]-30);
NSData *refinedData = [data subdataWithRange:range];

[fh writeData:nil];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:file contents:refinedData attributes:nil];
```